# Laravel Seeder Does Not Work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4.

When I first created a project, I did migration and seeding and all worked fine.

Now I deleted the database and wanted to redo migration and seeding again, migration worked, but seeder does not.

When I entered this command:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

the result I got was:

```
Seeding: xxxTableSeeder
```

No error, no result was seed. And I should have 4 tables to be seeded but none of it being seeded.

I tried

```
composer dump-autoload
```

but not working as well.

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call(ATableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(BTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(CTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(DTableSeeder::class);
}
}
```

ATableSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ATableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    DB::table('A')->insert([
        'username' => '',
        'firstname' => '',
        'lastname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'contact' => '',
        'password' =>,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ]);
}
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: does it point to same DB ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix yes, all tables that i want to seed are from same db

Comment: This is likely a syntax error, try `php -l xxxTableSeeder.php` to see if it has syntax errors. If so you'll need to track down the syntax error, usually running it directly will tell you the line `php xxxTableSeeder.php`

Comment: @sjdaws i got 'no syntax errors detected in xxxTableSeeder'

Comment: What does your `DatabaseSeeder.php` look like?

Comment: @Neat added into the question. check it out.

Comment: it keeps showing 'Seeding.....'

Comment: The password field in the array doesn’t have any quotes, is that an error?

Comment: @sjdaws it has value, just i removed it to show it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the '`timezone`' in `config/app.php` caused the issue. When I first migrated with the default timezone, which is 'UTC', everything works fine. Then I changed the timezone to 'UTC+8', and created_at and updated_at are working fine too. Then here comes the problem. I did migration again with the timezone 'UTC+8' and then stuck at the seeding part.

So now I **changed the timezone to 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'**, everything is working perfectly fine!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score -1):

You could try to run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Comment: i tried, it does redo migration but still no seed result.

Comment: did you tried to debug queries generated by seeder?

Comment: how to debug queries?

Comment: try something like `\DB::listen(function($sql) {
    var_dump($sql);
});`

Comment: it goes to second seed but still stops at second seed and no result

Comment: added ATableSeeder.php, perhaps you could help to check whats wrong? :)

Comment: what is your the APP_ENV value ? It must be NOT 'Production'

Comment: Production or Local are the same output

Answer (score -1):

Try run this in console:

```
php artisan dump
```

Just "dump", without autoload.

Works for me!

Good Luck, I hope be useful!

Comment: An answer to a question should not be phrased as "Try this..." or as another question. Answers should be concrete solutions to the posted question and offer explanation where needed. You should revise your answer to reflect these points.

Comment: What am I suppose to say? This solution worked for me once.